# Old science fiction story about plugging into a computer

Tags: story-identification, books

I once read a science fiction book, maybe from the 1980s, the plot of which I really can't remember except the ending. The main character found a way to "plug" into his computer and he was taken over by the computer, covered with wires and cords, etc. all while sitting in his chair at his desk.

Comment: I think there is a part in a Stephen King novel where a teenage boy becomes part of the computer system as you describe - hands connected to the keyboard, and his eyes are the screen - byt I can't remember which one.  Maybe Needful Things?

Comment: Not the same, but maybe useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terminal_Man

Comment: Not sure of the scifi book, but the description immediately reminded me of [Jimmy Jet and His TV Set](http://www.turnoffyourtv.com/poemsessays/jimmyjet.html).

Comment: That reminds me of one of the original superman films, where the computer becomes self aware and drags in the people using it.

Comment: @AidanO Superman III.

Comment: Reminds me of the ending of the computer game `Beneath a steel sky`.

Answer (score 3):

It might have been a book by Dean Koontz, I think it was called [Midnight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_%28Koontz_novel%29).

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in *Midnight*'s summary that indicates that it includes this scene. Anyone with more experience with the book?

Comment: Yeah, I've got Midnight, that fate happens just as described to some kid named 'Denny' who is then found by Loman (his father). I've right now skimmed through it to double check against my memory